# How to get the tokens from an NLTK Tree?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

So I have this tree returned to me

```
Tree('S', [('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('test', 'NN'), (',', ','), Tree('PERSON', [('Stackoverflow', 'NNP'), ('Users', 'NNP')]), ('.', '.')])
```

I can turn this into a nice python list like so

```
sentence = "This is a test, Stackoverflow Users."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
entities = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)
tree = repr(entities) # THIS VARIABLE IS THE TREE THAT IS RETURNED TO ME
# below this point it's about turning the tree into a python list
tree = (("[" + tree[5:-1] + "]")).replace("Tree", "").replace(")", "]").replace("(", "[")
tree = ast.literal_eval(tree) #you'll need to import ast (included with python)
```

now, the tree variable is this:

```
['S', [['This', 'DT'], ['is', 'VBZ'], ['a', 'DT'], ['test', 'NN'], [',', ','], ['ORGANIZATION', [['Stackoverflow', 'NNP']]], ['users', 'NNS'], ['.', '.']]]
```

When I try to iterate through and get a string of the sentence, I get

```
"This is a test, ORGANIZATION."
```

instead of the desired

```
"This is a test, Stackoverflow users."
```

I cannot simply use the sentence variable, I need to be able to get the sentence back from this list of lists. Any code snippets or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had to install nltk and download some packages using nltk.download(). Now I am stuck. What is ast? It is not defined in your code. Can you edit your question?

Comment: Sorry! try adding "import ast" to the top of your code, it's included with python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> yourtree = Tree('S', [('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('test', 'NN'), (',', ','), Tree('PERSON', [('Stackoverflow', 'NNP'), ('Users', 'NNP')]), ('.', '.')])
>>> yourtree.leaves()
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('test', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('Stackoverflow', 'NNP'), ('Users', 'NNP'), ('.', '.')]
>>> tokens, pos = zip(*yourtree.leaves())
>>> tokens
('This', 'is', 'a', 'test', ',', 'Stackoverflow', 'Users', '.')
>>> pos
('DT', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'NN', ',', 'NNP', 'NNP', '.')
```

See also: [How to Traverse an NLTK Tree object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689621/how-to-traverse-an-nltk-tree-object)