# Python (NLTK) - more efficient way to extract noun phrases?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, nltk, text-chunking

I've got a machine learning task involving a large amount of text data. I want to identify, and extract, noun-phrases in the training text so I can use them for feature construction later on in the pipeline. 
I've extracted the type of noun-phrases I wanted from text but I'm fairly new to NLTK, so I approached this problem in a way where I can break down each step in list comprehensions like you can see below.

But my real question is, am I reinventing the wheel here? Is there a faster way to do this that I'm not seeing?

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

myData = pd.read_excel("\User\train_.xlsx")
texts = myData['message']

# Defining a grammar & Parser
NP = "NP: {(<V\w+>|<NN\w?>)+.*<NN\w?>}"
chunkr = nltk.RegexpParser(NP)

tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(i) for i in texts]

tag_list = [nltk.pos_tag(w) for w in tokens]

phrases = [chunkr.parse(sublist) for sublist in tag_list]

leaves = [[subtree.leaves() for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter = lambda t: t.label == 'NP')] for tree in phrases]
```

flatten the list of lists of lists of tuples that we've ended up with, into
just a list of lists of tuples

```
leaves = [tupls for sublists in leaves for tupls in sublists]
```

Join the extracted terms into one bigram

```
nounphrases = [unigram[0][1]+' '+unigram[1][0] in leaves]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [Why is my NLTK function slow when processing the DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe), there's no need to iterate through all rows multiple times if you don't need intermediate steps.

With `ne_chunk` and solution from

- [NLTK Named Entity recognition to a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836058/nltk-named-entity-recognition-to-a-python-list) and
- [How can I extract GPE(location) using NLTK ne_chunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660547/how-can-i-extract-gpelocation-using-nltk-ne-chunk)

[code]:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk import RegexpParser
from nltk import Tree
import pandas as pd

def get_continuous_chunks(text, chunk_func=ne_chunk):
    chunked = chunk_func(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
    continuous_chunk = []
    current_chunk = []

    for subtree in chunked:
        if type(subtree) == Tree:
            current_chunk.append(" ".join([token for token, pos in subtree.leaves()]))
        elif current_chunk:
            named_entity = " ".join(current_chunk)
            if named_entity not in continuous_chunk:
                continuous_chunk.append(named_entity)
                current_chunk = []
        else:
            continue

    return continuous_chunk

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['This is a foo, bar sentence with New York city.', 
                           'Another bar foo Washington DC thingy with Bruce Wayne.']})

df['text'].apply(lambda sent: get_continuous_chunks((sent)))
```

[out]:

```
0                   [New York]
1    [Washington, Bruce Wayne]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

To use the custom `RegexpParser` :

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk import RegexpParser
from nltk import Tree
import pandas as pd

# Defining a grammar & Parser
NP = "NP: {(<V\w+>|<NN\w?>)+.*<NN\w?>}"
chunker = RegexpParser(NP)

def get_continuous_chunks(text, chunk_func=ne_chunk):
    chunked = chunk_func(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
    continuous_chunk = []
    current_chunk = []

    for subtree in chunked:
        if type(subtree) == Tree:
            current_chunk.append(" ".join([token for token, pos in subtree.leaves()]))
        elif current_chunk:
            named_entity = " ".join(current_chunk)
            if named_entity not in continuous_chunk:
                continuous_chunk.append(named_entity)
                current_chunk = []
        else:
            continue

    return continuous_chunk


df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['This is a foo, bar sentence with New York city.', 
                           'Another bar foo Washington DC thingy with Bruce Wayne.']})


df['text'].apply(lambda sent: get_continuous_chunks(sent, chunker.parse))
```

[out]:

```
0                  [bar sentence, New York city]
1    [bar foo Washington DC thingy, Bruce Wayne]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! The links are super helpful as well. Thanks @alvas ! Question, why do you write 'prev = None' ? when defining 'get_continuous_chunks'?

Comment: Oh that was a mistake, it's not necessary. I think I was using prev to check the history but actually only current_chunk is needed to check the history. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: hey @alvas, where did you come with that regex (NP = "NP: {(<V\w+>|<NN\w?>)+.*<NN\w?>}") - Is this a standard Noun phrase detection standard?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest referring to this prior thread:
[Extracting all Nouns from a text file using nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587667/extracting-all-nouns-from-a-text-file-using-nltk)

They suggest using TextBlob as the easiest way to achieve this (if not the one that is most efficient in terms of processing) and the discussion there addresses your question.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
txt = """Natural language processing (NLP) is a field of computer science, artificial intelligence, and computational linguistics concerned with the interactions between computers and human (natural) languages."""
blob = TextBlob(txt)
print(blob.noun_phrases)
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the discussion on this question! Textblob definitely has advantages over the sometimes-bulky NLTK. However, your offered solution doesn't allow for customized parsing to occur - which ultimately could be a stronger pro for NLTK.

Answer (score 1):

The above methods didn't give me the required results. Following is the function that I would suggest

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk import RegexpParser
from nltk import Tree
import re


def get_noun_phrases(text):
    pos = pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
    count = 0
    half_chunk = ""
    for word, tag in pos:
        if re.match(r"NN.*", tag):
            count+=1
            if count>=1:
                half_chunk = half_chunk + word + " "
        else:
            half_chunk = half_chunk+"---"
            count = 0
    half_chunk = re.sub(r"-+","?",half_chunk).split("?")
    half_chunk = [x.strip() for x in half_chunk if x!=""]
    return half_chunk
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Constituent-Treelib](https://github.com/Halvani/Constituent-Treelib) library, which can be installed via: `pip install constituent-treelib` does excatly what you are looking for in few lines of code. In order to extract noun (or any other) phrases, perform the following steps.

```py
from constituent_treelib import ConstituentTree

# First, we have to provide a sentence that should be parsed
sentence = "I've got a machine learning task involving a large amount of text data."

# Then, we define the language that should be considered with respect to the underlying models 
language = ConstituentTree.Language.English

# You can also specify the desired model for the language ("Small" is selected by default)
spacy_model_size = ConstituentTree.SpacyModelSize.Medium

# Next, we must create the neccesary NLP pipeline. 
# If you wish, you can instruct the library to download and install the models automatically
nlp = ConstituentTree.create_pipeline(language, spacy_model_size) # , download_models=True

# Now, we can instantiate a ConstituentTree object and pass it the sentence and the NLP pipeline
tree = ConstituentTree(sentence, nlp)

# Finally, we can extract the phrases
tree.extract_all_phrases()
```

Result...

```py
{'S': ["I 've got a machine learning task involving a large amount of text data ."],
 'PP': ['of text data'],
 'VP': ["'ve got a machine learning task involving a large amount of text data",
  'got a machine learning task involving a large amount of text data',
  'involving a large amount of text data'],
 'NML': ['machine learning'],
 'NP': ['a machine learning task involving a large amount of text data',
  'a machine learning task',
  'a large amount of text data',
  'a large amount',
  'text data']}
```

If you only want the noun phrases, just pick them out with `tree.extract_all_phrases()['NP']`

```py
['a machine learning task involving a large amount of text data',
 'a machine learning task',
 'a large amount of text data',
 'a large amount',
 'text data']
```