# NLP: Validate a sentence against a given grammar

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have a corpus of English sentences

```
sentences = [
    "Mary had a little lamb.",
    "John has a cute black pup.",
    "I ate five apples."
]
```

and a grammar (for the sake of simplicity)

```
grammar = ('''
    NP: {<NNP><VBZ|VBD><DT><JJ>*<NN><.>} # NP
    ''')
```

I wish to filter out the sentences which don't conform to the grammar. 
Is there a built-in NLTK function which can achieve this?
In the above example, first two sentences follow the pattern of my grammar, but not the last one.

Comment: If you're just extracting nouns, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49564176/610569

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Write a grammar, check that it parses, iterate through the subtrees and look for the non-terminals you're looking for, e.g. `NP`

See:

- [Python (NLTK) - more efficient way to extract noun phrases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564176/python-nltk-more-efficient-way-to-extract-noun-phrases)
- [How to Traverse an NLTK Tree object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689621/how-to-traverse-an-nltk-tree-object)

Code:

```
import nltk

grammar = ('''
    NP: {<NNP><VBZ|VBD><DT><JJ>*<NN><.>} # NP
    ''')

sentences = [
    "Mary had a little lamb.",
    "John has a cute black pup.",
    "I ate five apples."
]

def has_noun_phrase(sentence):
    parsed = chunkParser.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
    for subtree in parsed:
        if type(subtree) == nltk.Tree and subtree.label() == 'NP':
            return True
    return False

chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
for sentence in sentences:
    print(has_noun_phrase(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

NLTK supports POS tagging, you can firstly apply POS tagging to your sentences, and then compare with the pre-defined grammar. Below is an example of using NLTK POS tagging.

[image]

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem. My grammar has a pre-defined structure and I wish to validate whether the grammar returned by nltk.pos_tag() is _similar_ or not. I could write my own parser to validate my regex grammar against the one returned but I'm looking for an inbuilt validator.

Comment: I don't know, maybe you need to do it my your own. Sorry.